# Automatically nested for loops in python

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-loops

I am aware that two collections can be accessed simultaneously using

```
for i,j in zip([1,2,3],[4,5,6]):
    print i,j

1 4
2 5
3 6
```

What I would like to do is something like this:

```
for i,j in [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]:
    print i,j

1 4
1 5
1 6
2 4
2 5
2 6
3 4
3 5
3 6
```

I want python to automatically create the nested for loop for me. I would like to avoid using many nested for loops in my code when the list dimension gets up to 5 or 6. Is this possible?

Comment: @delnan (4) == Sven's response which is what I was asking for.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try

```
for i, j in itertools.product([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]):
    print i, j
```

Comment: Took a look at the docs and I need to upgrade to python 2.6. Appears to do exactly what I wanted though. Will check in 8 minutes. Thanks.

Comment: @puddingfox: You can also copy the implementation from the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), but it will be less efficient than the Real Thing.

Comment: Itertools rocks.  It is worth the time to learn the tools in that toolbox.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> [[x,y] for x in [1,2,3] for y in [4,5,6]]
[[1, 4], [1, 5], [1, 6], [2, 4], [2, 5], [2, 6], [3, 4], [3, 5], [3, 6]]
```

It should be pretty easy to get what you want out of the resulting list.

Comment: But that's harder to generalize for lists nested n times.

Comment: Is it? Maybe I don't quite understand but if you simply do `[[x,y,z] for x in [1,2,3] for y in [4,5,6] for z in [7,8,9]]` it should scale, no?

Comment: well it _does_ already look a little unwieldly compared to using product. Howver the big difference is that nested LC has the dimensions hardcoded - whereas product can work with any number of dimensions

Answer (score 0):

I've had some cases where the logic for what needs to be iterated over is rather complex -- so you can always break that piece out into it's own generator:

```
def it():
    i = 0
    for r in xrange(rows):
        for c in xrange(cols):
            if i >= len(images):
                return
            yield r, c, images[i], contents[i]
            i += 1

for r, c, image, content in it():
    # do something...
```

But typically I find just spelling simple nested loops out to be better than obfuscating what you're looping over into a call to some other code.  If you have more than 2-3 loops nested, the code probably needs refactoring anyway.